# How do I use mathematica for encryption if someone gave me their Public Key in PGP format?

Tags: cryptography

How do I do Mathematica to a encrypt a message when someone has given me their public PGP key?

Does Mathematica have this functionality? Could I use Mathematica `GenerateAsymmetricKeyPair[]` to share a PGP key?

Comment: While I am interested to know if Mathematica has this functionality as well, this is one of the cases where I would highly recommend just using the dedicated software for it (`gpg`) if you're planning on using this in anything resembling a production style environment. Cryptography is not a very DIY friendly field. I couldn't figure out how to import an example PGP key myself, so I'm not entirely sure it can be done.

Comment: Agreed it doesn't look doable but here's to hoping that it does

Comment: A question related to your third one ("Could I use Mma [...] to share a PGP key?) is [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/242143/how-to-get-v12-0-to-print-pgp-public-key-and-secret-key-blocks-after-generating), " Using Mma to print the keys in the strict sense is possible (see @SjoerdSmit's answer [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/242043/after-using-generateasymmetrickeypair-how-to-print-the-two-keys-in-hex)), so the outstanding issue is whether one can get Mma to take the other required info and put it together with the key to generate the key block.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately Mathematica does not support PGP key import and encryption/decryption.
However, as of v 12.2 it does support import of PEM files (keys, certificates, etc)