# After using GenerateAsymmetricKeyPair[], how to print the two keys in hex?

Tags: cryptography

After using `GenerateAsymmetricKeyPair` in Mathematica 12, how can I print the two keys in hex?

There is probably a simple answer that I'm missing, but there's nothing about this in the documentation for `GenerateAsymmetricKeyPair`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think `BaseEncode` is the most direct way to convert the ByteArray to a hex string. For example, to get the public key in hex:

```
pair = GenerateAsymmetricKeyPair[]
BaseEncode[
  pair["PublicKey"]["PublicByteArray"],
  "Base16"
]
```

The same will work for `pair["PrivateKey"]["PrivateByteArray"]`

## Edit

It seems like 2-argument `BaseEncode` is not supported in V12.0. You can use the following instead:

```
ToUpperCase @ StringJoin[
  Map[IntegerString[#, 16, 2]&,
    ImportByteArray[pair["PublicKey"]["PublicByteArray"], "Byte"]
  ]
]
```

Comment: Thanks for this. But it's telling me `BaseEncode::argx: BaseEncode called with 2 arguments; 1 argument is expected.` I've no idea why this is. The documentation says `BaseEncode` should be able to take a specification of the required coding as its second argument. Perhaps this is new to 12.2? I'm using 12.0.

Comment: @ool That's a shame. See the updated answer for a method that should work in V12.0.

Comment: Thanks, @SjoerdSmit - that works fine. Many thanks for your help. Now I will post another question about how to extract a fingerprint, also in hex.

Comment: I'm putting this in a comment because it's maybe not suitable for a separate q, but when I specify a 4kbit key by using `GenerateAsymmetricKeyPair[
 Method -> <|"Type" -> "RSA", "KeySize" -> 4096|>]`, your code prints a string of length 1k hex chars ~ 0.5kB ~ 4kb which is correct for the public key in the strict sense but not for the key *block* which should contain some other info too (e.g. I have a 4kb pubkey with a block of length amost 12kb). Is there a way to get Mma to print a whole key block? gpg4win is refusing to import an ASCII file containing only the 0.5k printed hex chars.

Comment: @ool There is no built-in functionality for this. If you can specify how the gpg4win key block should be generated, please detail it in a new question and me or someone else can probably help you. I don't know the implementation details myself.

Comment: Many thanks for your help, @SjoerdSmit . Unfortunately I can't find that information. It is quite ironic that the way to make a key block from a public security key, which does not itself require security protection, is so obscure, at least to non-techies like me. I have posted [this other question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/242143/how-to-get-v12-0-to-print-pgp-public-key-and-secret-key-blocks-after-generating) and added a bounty.