# How to get v12.0 to print PGP public key and secret key BLOCKS after generating a key pair using GenerateAsymmetricKeyPair[]?

Tags: cryptography

This question is related to, but not the same as, two others I recently asked about using Mathematica's PGP functionality: "[After using GenerateAsymmetricKeyPair[], how to print the two keys in hex?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/242043/after-using-generateasymmetrickeypair-how-to-print-the-two-keys-in-hex)" and "[Given a PGP public key, how can I extract its PGP fingerprint in hex, using v12.0?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/242073/given-a-pgp-public-key-how-can-i-extract-its-pgp-fingerprint-in-hex-using-v12)". As before, I am using Mathematica v12.0.

Having generated a PGP key pair using `GenerateAsymmetricKeyPair[]`, **how can I print the two key *blocks*** in the format in which they are usually stated, i.e. broken into 64-character lines in base64, like this:

```
-----BEGIN PGP PUBLIC KEY BLOCK-----
[optional version info]
[blank line]
[several 64-character lines in base64]
[5-character final line in base64, beginning with "="]
-----END PGP PUBLIC KEY BLOCK-----
```

This is the standard format if you want to send someone your public key in the body text of an email, for example.

A private key block looks similar:

```
-----BEGIN PGP PRIVATE KEY BLOCK-----
[optional version info]
[blank line]
[several 64-character lines in base64]
[a line in base64 of possibly fewer than 64 characters, ending with "=="]
[5-character final line in base64, beginning with "="]
-----END PGP PUBLIC KEY BLOCK-----
```

I realise that since the base64 string in the public key block contains other information as well as the public key in the strict sense - and similarly for the private key block, which in fact contains the public key as well as the private key in the strict sense - some information (including name, email address, and passphrase if specified) may need to be processed by Mathematica before `GenerateAsymmetricKeyPair[]` is called, and if not before then it certainly will after. But how can I actually get Mathematica to produce key blocks in this standard format?

[*Edit by @ool: This was not a great description by me of what's in the armoured ASCII versions of the two keys. The canonical source here is [section 11 of RFC 4880](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4880#section-11), which **specifies** that minimal blocks in each case are constructed from the relevant key packet (public or private) followed by a userid packet, with the combination of those two items then followed by a CRC24 checksum; and which **advocates** that the userid packet in the private key block "should" be followed by a self-signature because that will allow the extraction of the public key, while commenting that self-signature is not necessary, for example when a transferable public key accompanies the transferable private key.*]

Comment: If there is no way to do this, then we would be in the strange position that Mathematica can generate a keypair of the kind used for PGP public key encryption but it can't print the public key block in the standard form for emailing to someone. I hope this isn't so!

Comment: Just a quick thought that you could also just use the output of the `gpg` command, eg `RunProcess[{"gpg", "--help"}]` rather than trying to force Mathematica to do it. It depends on your goals though, just in case this helps you save time :)

Comment: Similar question posted [here](https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/2236721).

Comment: If ```ga```is the output of ```GenerateAsymetricKeyPair```, then ```BaseEncode[ga["PublicKey"]["PublicByteArray"],"Base64"]``` returns the key as Base64. In the last line, the = sign is followed by the crc24 hash of the key in Base64 (4 characters). The Mathematica ```Hash```function can compute a crc32 hash, but not crc24. So you would need to create the hash code.

Comment: Thanks, @Jean-Pierre. But before the 5-char final line a key block contains much more info than just the key in the strict sense put into Base64. Or are you saying that the key followed by its 4-char crc24 hash would make a minimal functioning block? (Then there is the further question about the private key block.)

Comment: I was just saying that to reproduce the block, you need the Base64 version of the key and the hash. Since the version is optional, this appears to be sufficient to format the block (I am not a PGP user, so I am not familiar with all the requirements). By the way, if ```ga``` is the output of key generation, the following lists several properties of the key that can be accessed by replacing "Properties" with a name in the list: ```ga[["PrivateKey"]]["Properties"]```.

Comment: In the public key block, there is at least usually, perhaps mandatorily, more than just the key and the hash, including the key owner's email address. But I have no idea how to process this information to make the block. I've tried various things with gpg's "armouring" function but to no avail. It is a bit strange that with Mathematica one can generate a key pair, use the keys, and even get them out in raw form, but not get them out in standard block form. If I had lots of rep I'd offer it all as a bounty for this question :-)

Answer (score 5):

> **UPDATE:** Partial implementation of RFC 2440 to generate a Public Key ASCII armor block from `GenerateAsymmetricKeyPair[]`. The Base64 data will include 3 types of packets: **Public Key, User ID, Signature**. RFC 2440 can be quite confusing, particularly concerning the signature and the fields to hash and encrypt. **I cannot guarantee the accuracy of the code**. The purpose is to show the extent of what is involved.

Some functions:

```
crc24[bytes_] := (
  (* create a BitVector *)
  
  crcBV = CreateDataStructure["BitVector", 24];
  
  (* initialize the bit vector with 0xb704ce *)
  
  initial = {1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 
    0, 1, 1, 1, 0};
  k = 23;
  Map[If[# == 1, crcBV["BitSet", k--], k--] &, initial];
  
  (* polynome info *)
  
  poly = {23, 18, 17, 14, 11, 10, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 1};
  
  (* process each bit of data *)
  Map[
   (b = #;
     i = 7;
     While[i >= 0,
      If[BitAnd[b, BitShiftLeft[1, i]] != 0, v = 1, v = 0];
      xorResult = BitXor[crcBV["BitGet", 23], v];
      k = 23;
      While[k > 0,
       If[MemberQ[poly, k],
        (* true *)
        
        bx = BitXor[crcBV["BitGet", k - 1], xorResult];
        If[bx != 0, crcBV["BitSet", k], crcBV["BitClear", k]],
        (* false *)
        
        If[crcBV["BitGet", k - 1] != 0, crcBV["BitSet", k], 
          crcBV["BitClear", k]];
        ];
       k--;
       ];
      If[xorResult != 0, crcBV["BitSet", 0], crcBV["BitClear", 0]];
      i--
      ]) &
   , bytes // Normal];
  
  bitList = Map[crcBV["BitGet", #] &, Flatten@Range[23, 0, -1]];
  pList = Partition[bitList, 8];
  BaseEncode@
   ByteArray@
    Map[(#[[8]] + #[[7]]*2 + #[[6]]*4 + #[[5]]*8 + #[[4]]*16 + \
#[[3]]*32 + #[[2]]*64 + #[[1]]*128) &, pList]
  )

toBitList[bytes_ByteArray] := (
  Flatten@Map[IntegerDigits[#, 2, 8] &, bytes // Normal]
  )

toInteger[bytes_ByteArray] := (
  Total[MapIndexed[#1*(2^(#2 - 1)) &, 
     Reverse[toBitList[bytes]]]][[1]]
  )

toByteArray[int_Integer] := (
  digits2 = IntegerDigits[int, 2];
  padded = 
   PadLeft[digits2, 
    Mod[8 - Mod[Length[digits2], 8], 8] + Length[digits2]];
  ByteArray[Map[FromDigits[#, 2] &, Partition[padded, 8]]]
  )

toMultiprecision[bytes_ByteArray] := (
  bl = BitLength[toInteger[bytes]];
  part = Partition[IntegerDigits[bl, 2, 16], 8];
  map = Map[(#[[8]] + #[[7]]*2 + #[[6]]*4 + #[[5]]*8 + #[[4]]*16 + \
#[[3]]*32 + #[[2]]*64 + #[[1]]*128) &, part];
  ByteArray[Join[map, bytes // Normal]]
  )

toMultiprecisionByteArray[int_Integer] := (
  toMultiprecision[toByteArray[int]]
  )

addPacketHeader[tagType_String, body_ByteArray] := (
  bodyLength = Length[body];
  encodedLength = toByteArray[bodyLength];
  If[Length[encodedLength] == 3, 
   encodedLength = Prepend[encodedLength // Normal, 0]];
  blength = BitLength[bodyLength];
  Which[
   tagType == "PublicKey",
   tag = Which[blength <= 8, 2^^10011000, blength <= 16, 2^^10011001, 
     blength > 16, 2^^10011010],
   
   tagType == "UserID",
   tag = Which[blength <= 8, 2^^10110100, blength <= 16, 2^^10110101, 
     blength > 16, 2^^10110110],
   
   tagType == "Signature",
   tag = Which[blength <= 8, 2^^10001000, blength <= 16, 2^^10001001, 
     blength > 16, 2^^10001010],

   tagType == "PrivateKey", 
   tag = Which[blength <= 8, 2^^10010100, blength <= 16, 2^^10010101, 
    blength > 16, 2^^10010110]
   ];
  Join[{tag}, encodedLength, body]
  )

addSubPacketHeader[tagType_String, body_ByteArray] := (
  bodyLength = Length[body] + 1; (* length includes the type byte *)
 
   encodedLength = toByteArray[bodyLength];
  If[Length[encodedLength] == 4, 
   encodedLength = Prepend[encodedLength // Normal, 0]];
  If[Length[encodedLength] == 3, 
   encodedLength = Flatten@Prepend[encodedLength // Normal, {0, 0}]];
  blength = BitLength[bodyLength];
  Which[
   tagType == "SignatureCreationTime",
   type = 2,
   
   tagType == "KeyID",
   type = 16;
   
   ];
  Join[encodedLength, {type}, body]
  )

addHashedOrNoneSubPacketHeader[body_] := (
  bodyLength = Length[body];
  encodedLength = toByteArray[bodyLength];
  If[Length[encodedLength] == 1, 
   encodedLength = Prepend[encodedLength // Normal, 0]];
  Join[encodedLength, body]
  )

getUserIDPacketForSignature[uID_ByteArray] := (
  length = Length[uID];
  length32 = 
   Map[(#[[8]] + #[[7]]*2 + #[[6]]*4 + #[[5]]*8 + #[[4]]*16 + \
#[[3]]*32 + #[[2]]*64 + #[[1]]*128) &, 
    Partition[IntegerDigits[length, 2, 32], 8]];
  ByteArray[Join[{16^^b4}, length32, userID]]
  )

getTrailerData[sigData_] := (
  length = Length[sigData];
  length32 = 
   Map[(#[[8]] + #[[7]]*2 + #[[6]]*4 + #[[5]]*8 + #[[4]]*16 + \
#[[3]]*32 + #[[2]]*64 + #[[1]]*128) &, 
    Partition[IntegerDigits[length, 2, 32], 8]];
  ByteArray[Join[{4}, {16^^FF}, length32]]
  )
```

Key creation:

```
keyPair = GenerateAsymmetricKeyPair[]
```

The code:

```
(* =============== Public Key Packet ============= *)
rsa = 1;
version = 4;
timeOfCreation = 
  toByteArray[
   QuantityMagnitude[
    DateDifference[{1970, 1, 1}, {2021, 4, 9}, "Second"]]];
publicKeyAlgorithm = rsa; 
mpPublicByteArray = 
  toMultiprecision[keyPair["PublicKey"]["PublicByteArray"]];
mpPublicExponent = 
  toMultiprecisionByteArray[keyPair["PublicKey"]["PublicExponent"]];
bodyKeyPacket = 
  ByteArray[
   Join[{version}, timeOfCreation, {publicKeyAlgorithm}, 
    mpPublicByteArray, mpPublicExponent]];
keyPacket = addPacketHeader["PublicKey", bodyKeyPacket];

(* ============= Fingerprint and Key ID =========\[Equal]*)

fingerprint = Hash[ByteArray@keyPacket, "SHA", "ByteArray"];
keyID = Take[fingerprint, -8];

(* ============\[Equal] User ID Packet ============= *)

userID = StringToByteArray["John <test@ygtjispt.com>"];
userIDPacket = addPacketHeader["UserID", userID];
userIDDataForSignature = getUserIDPacketForSignature[userID];
hashedUserID = Hash[userIDDataForSignature, "SHA", "ByteArray"];

(* ============= Signature Packet ============ *)
sha1 = 2;
signatureVersion = 4;
signatureType = 16; (* certification User ID and Public Key packet *)
\
signatureAlgorithm = rsa;
hashAlgorithm = sha1;
signatureCreationTime = 
  toByteArray[
   QuantityMagnitude[
    DateDifference[{1970, 1, 1}, {2021, 4, 10}, "Second"]]];
hashedSubPacket1 = 
  addSubPacketHeader["SignatureCreationTime", signatureCreationTime];
hashedSubpackets = addHashedOrNoneSubPacketHeader[hashedSubPacket1];
nonHashedSubPacket1 = addSubPacketHeader["KeyID", keyID];
nonHashedSubPackets = 
  addHashedOrNoneSubPacketHeader[nonHashedSubPacket1];
signatureData = 
  Join[{signatureVersion}, {signatureType}, {signatureAlgorithm}, \
{hashAlgorithm}, hashedSubpackets];
hashedSignatureData = 
  Hash[ByteArray[signatureData], "SHA", "ByteArray"];
highBits16 = Take[hashedSignatureData // Normal, 2];
trailerData = getTrailerData[signatureData];
hashedTrailer = Hash[trailerData, "SHA", "ByteArray"];

(* Encrypted data *)

hashField = 
  Join[fingerprint, hashedUserID, hashedSignatureData, 
   hashedTrailer];
encryptedData = 
  toMultiprecision[Encrypt[keyPair["PrivateKey"], hashField]["Data"]];

signaturePacketBody = 
  ByteArray@
   Join[signatureData, nonHashedSubPackets, highBits16, encryptedData];
signaturePacket = addPacketHeader["Signature", signaturePacketBody];

(* ============= Final block =================== *)

finalArray = 
  ByteArray@Join[keyPacket, userIDPacket, signaturePacket];
pKey64 = BaseEncode[finalArray];
crc24Base64 = crc24[finalArray];
Print["-----BEGIN PGP PUBLIC KEY BLOCK-----\n", "Version: OpenPGP\n", \
"Comment: Created with Mathematica 12.2\n", "\n", 
 InsertLinebreaks[pKey64, 
  64], "\n", "=", crc24Base64, "\n", "-----END PGP PUBLIC KEY \
BLOCK-----"]
```

The result:

[image]

Importation into PGPTool:

[image]

Producing a **Private Key block**, which includes the data for both the public and private key, is a more complicated undertaking, dealing with passphrase, private key encryption, deprecated versions and all. One thing required is the value of **p** and **q**, the original prime factors. The following function may assist:

```
(* extracts the prime numbers p and q from the data generated by \
GenerateAsymetricKeypair[] - required for a Private Key packet*)

getpq[n_, d_, e_] := (
  k = d*e - 1;
  t = 0;
  r = NestWhile[t++; #/2 &, k, EvenQ, 1];
  i = 1;
  While[i < 100,
   g = RandomInteger[{0, n - 1}];
   y = PowerMod[g, r, n];
   If[y == 1 || y == n - 1, Goto[loop]];
   j = 1;
   While[j < t - 1,
    x = PowerMod[y, 2, n];
    If[x == 1, Goto[end]];
    If[x == n - 1, Goto[loop]];
    y = x;
    j++;
    ];
   x = PowerMod[y, 2, n];
   If[x == 1, Goto[end]];
   Label[loop];
   i++;
   ];
  Label[end];
  p = GCD[y - 1, n];
  q = n/p;
  {p, q}
  )

(* usage of the above function and related data required
 to build a Private Key packet *)
{p, q} = getpq[
   keyPair["PublicKey"]["PublicModulus"],
   keyPair["PrivateKey"]["PrivateExponent"],
   keyPair["PublicKey"]["PublicExponent"]
   ];
   u = ModularInverse[p, q];
mpD = toMultiprecision[keyPair["PrivateKey"]["PrivateByteArray"]];
mpP = toMultiprecisionByteArray[p];
mpQ = toMultiprecisionByteArray[q];
mpU = toMultiprecisionByteArray[u];
(* ..... and more *)
```

> **ORIGINAL ANSWER (NO LONGER RELEVANT):** The example below uses the `PublicByteArray` representing the key to demonstrate formatting a block. This array is just the `PublicModulus` converted to a byte array. **This byte array is not formatted according to the OpenPGP standard**. It is missing several pieces of information that would have to be added for the resulting block to be valid.

Here is an example of producing a block for the public key. First we need a function to produce the crc24 hash. I wanted to play with BitVector (introduced in 12.1) so I created the following (non-optimized) function, which gives the four base64 characters hash. I guess this would not work with 12.0.

```
crc24[bytes_] := (
  (* create a BitVector *)
  
  crcBV = CreateDataStructure["BitVector", 24];
  
  (* initialize the bit vector with 0xb704ce *)
  
  initial = {1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 
    0, 1, 1, 1, 0};
  k = 23;
  Map[If[# == 1, crcBV["BitSet", k--], k--] &, initial];
  
  (* polynome info *)
  
  poly = {23, 18, 17, 14, 11, 10, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 1};
  
  (* process each bit of data *)
  Map[
   (b = #;
     i = 7;
     While[i >= 0,
      If[BitAnd[b, BitShiftLeft[1, i]] != 0, v = 1, v = 0];
      xorResult = BitXor[crcBV["BitGet", 23], v];
      k = 23;
      While[k > 0,
       If[MemberQ[poly, k],
        (* true *)
        
        bx = BitXor[crcBV["BitGet", k - 1], xorResult];
        If[bx != 0, crcBV["BitSet", k], crcBV["BitClear", k]],
        (* false *)
        
        If[crcBV["BitGet", k - 1] != 0, crcBV["BitSet", k], 
          crcBV["BitClear", k]];
        ];
       k--;
       ];
      If[xorResult != 0, crcBV["BitSet", 0], crcBV["BitClear", 0]];
      i--
      ]) &
   , bytes // Normal];
  
  bitList = Map[crcBV["BitGet", #] &, Flatten@Range[23, 0, -1]];
  pList = Partition[bitList, 8];
  BaseEncode@
   ByteArray@
    Map[(#[[8]] + #[[7]]*2 + #[[6]]*4 + #[[5]]*8 + #[[4]]*16 + \
#[[3]]*32 + #[[2]]*64 + #[[1]]*128) &, pList]
  )
```

The following generates the keys and prints a public key block (with a bogus Version and Comment).

```
keyPair = GenerateAsymmetricKeyPair[];
pKeyArray = keyPair["PublicKey"]["PublicByteArray"];
pKey64 = BaseEncode[pKeyArray];
crc24Base64 = crc24[pKeyArray];
Print["-----BEGIN PGP PUBLIC KEY BLOCK-----\n",
 "Version: OpenPGP\n",
 "Comment: Created with Mathematica 12.2\n",
 "\n",
 InsertLinebreaks[pKey64, 64], "\n",
 "=", crc24Base64, "\n",
 "-----END PGP PUBLIC KEY BLOCK-----"
 ]
```

[image]

Comment: Many thanks for this! Unfortunately I can't test it, because I only have 12.0. Have you tested the output with say PGPTool to see whether it is recognised as a key block? Also how can one get a private key block? That needs to include both keys in the strict sense but I don't know in what order. If you can post the output as text, I will see whether PGPTool accepts it.

Comment: See my update in the answer.

Comment: I'm not sure about "several" other pieces of information being mandatory to include. See [this answer](https://superuser.com/questions/764465/how-to-ascii-armor-my-public-key-without-installing-gpg). This is [so tantalising](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4880#section-6).

Comment: Once you have the key in the proper format, then yes it is easy to produce the block and send your key, but the format includes fields in a specific order with proper headers identifying each type of data and its size. These fields include the modulus and the exponent for the public key itself, as well as UserID (email or other) and a signature packet requiring the computation of hash for specific fields followed by encryption with the private key for authentication. This is much more than simply providing a byte array of the modulus.

Comment: Brilliant, @Jean-Pierre - many thanks for all this work. If the key block is recognised by PGPTool then I count that as a complete success where the public key is concerned. I strongly doubt any other PGP program would fail to recognise it if it's fine for PGPTool. Unfortunately I only have Mathematica 12.0 so I am getting "=BaseEncode[lengthy function here]" after the 780 Base64 chars. This may well be the time for me to upgrade.

Comment: Thanks, @Jean-Pierre. I have added another bounty and will award it to your answer when the software here allows me, which will be after another 24 hours. I've now upgraded to v12.2 and your code works fine. Is it easy for you to add some lines that will print out a private key block as well as the public key one? I've fiddled with the code to do this after a fashion, but I must be doing something wrong because PGPTools thinks both blocks are public. Having pored through RFC4880 I still don't understand the blength line in your code and what it achieves with the packet tags.

Comment: This is getting complicated. I updated my answer with some info regarding the Private Key block, but did not generate one. I am using the old type of tag for packet headers: these encode the type of packet (bits 5 to 2) and the length of the length field that follows (bits 1 to 0). This length field is of variable octet length and holds the length of the packet body. ```blength```uses BitLength to get the minimum number of bits necessary to represent the integer corresponding to the length of the packet body. This indicates how many octets are necessary to hold the length integer.

Comment: This is so complicated for something that in principle should be straightforward and hopefully will be in a future Mma upgrade. While the indication of acceptance by PGPTool is highly positive, unfortunately it's impossible to test whether this answer works for encryption unless one also has the private key. (Sorry - I posted this first as an answer by mistake, rather than as a comment.)

Comment: @tell I did produce a message in PGTool using the Public Key I had loaded. The message was "This is a test". I was able to decipher the Session key using my private key and use this session key bytes to generate a Symmetric key with the proper parameters. This symmetric key was then used to decipher tha actual message bytes. The deciphered message was ZIP compressed and I could not figure out an easy way to unzip a ZIP byte array in Mathematica. I finally use an INFLATE online service and recovered the following text: ```˜btext.asc`tWHThis is a test```. So encryption works.

Comment: But how can we get the "-----BEGIN PGP PRIVATE KEY BLOCK-----" ? that's the other part of this question?

Comment: @Jean-Pierre - How can I make the private key block from the information in the answer? Whatever combination of packets I've tried inserting, starting with `keyPair["PrivateKey"]["PrivateByteArray"]` and attempting to follow RFC 4880, the block is still thought by PGPTool to be public even if it is within "`-----(...)PRIVATE(...)-----`" tags.

Comment: I am working on an implementation of RFC 4880. I'll post something if/when I get it  completed. The potential for error in trying to do only bits and pieces here and there is great. Note that the ASCII Armor header line does not matter that much. What is important are the packets included in the Base64 data. For example, PGPTool produces a Public Key Block with 5 packets (public key, User ID, signature, public subkey, signature). A Private Key Block contains 10 packets (private key, User ID, signature, private subkey, signature, plus the 5 packets of the public key).

Comment: @Jean-Pierre - Can the subkeys and their signatures not be omitted? Or perhaps the packet titles are still needed. Or maybe PGPTool can only accept key blocks with 5 and 10 packets, in accordance with what it writes? This is above my head :-(