# With v12.2, how to call gpg (or gpg4win) and tell it to generate RSA key pair and to return private and public key blocks and fingerprint?

Tags: cryptography

Using Mathematica v12.2, is it possible to call gpg (or gpg4win) and then tell it to generate an RSA key pair and to return

- private and public PGP key blocks in standand format
- and the 40 hex-character PGP fingerprint,

with all three then processable as Mathematica variables?

(So for example if the fingerprint did not have characters 9-12 spelling "ABC1" you could loop back and keep generating asymmetric key pairs until you found one that did have a fingerprint that met the criterion, and when you did you would have both its public key block and its private key block, as well as the "nice" fingerprint itself.)

Comment: Have you seen [How to print PGP public key and secret key BLOCKS after generating a key pair using GenerateAsymmetricKeyPair](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/242143/27951)? In addition to the solution proposed, which goes perhaps further than you need in formatting the results, but should also accomplish what you want, there is [mention in the comments](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/242143/how-to-get-v12-0-to-print-pgp-public-key-and-secret-key-blocks-after-generating#comment611362_242143) of the possibility to use `RunProcess` to just run gpg from within Mathematica.

Comment: Many thanks for this. Yes, I saw that question and answer. The answer goes almost the whole way, but not quite because it doesn't yield the private key block, and therefore one could get a key pair with a "nice" fingerprint but only have the public key block and not the private one. If I knew of a way to get the private key block after generating a pair with `GenerateAsymmetricKeyPair` then the whole problem would be solved. But that seems to be a tough ask, so I'm kinda thinking running gpg from within Mathematica is the way to go, although am unsure how to implement.